# how to change multiple asp.net textbox or labels or tags in different style with CSS or CSSClass or in C#?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="givennametb" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Width="145px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="familynametb" runat="server" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" Width="145px"></asp:TextBox>
```

I wrote this piece of code. Now I want to change `bordercolor` of `givennametb` `textBox` to blue and `familynametb` to red.

I do not want to do it inline with`BorderColor:"blue/red"`. I want to use CSS/CSSClass. I am using C# with ASP.NET. If I do `cssClass="textbox"` and try to change in style, all tags are changing to same color. I want to change separately.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, ASP.Net is going to render the control ASP:Text for the web browser in a `<Input type="text">` of a `<form>` HTML, so you can use a CCS Selector with the Id of control to modify the border color of textBox.

```css
input#givennametb{
       border:1px solid blue;
    }

 input#familynametb{
       border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<input id="givennametb" type="text" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="familynametb" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I really appreciate your participant. Actually I want to know that, there is any way to do as I mentioned or not. I am learning ASP.NET. So I do not want to use any html tag here. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input.textbox#givennametb{
       border:1px solid blue;
    }

 input.textbox#familynametb{
       border:1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<input id="givennametb" type="text" class="textbox" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="familynametb" type="text" class="textbox" />
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I really appreciate your participant. Actually I want to know that, there is any way to do as I mentioned or not. I am learning ASP.NET. So I do not want to use any html tag here. thanks.